# Boolean modifier difference between curved objects not working well

Tags: modifiers

I tried to make difference between the two concentric cylinders. The boolean operation works well for the straight ones. But after I added the curve modifier to both cylinders, and did the difference again. There were some redundant faces left for the large cylinders.

Why did this happen? Could someone give some hint or advice? Thanks!

My file can be downloaded here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l1vw12idg72vccn/AACewT_XSUhBMdP1CqA8L5zsa?dl=0

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOHVr.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. select your cylinder.005
2. go to edit mode
3. select only the end circle of your cylinder

[image]

4. press CTRL-E -> extrude along normals
5. make it a bit longer with mouse
6. same procedure on other side
7. result: (boolean to exact)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have been able to extrude faces a little bit like 0.005, and then merge the edges back. So it looks like original cylinder...Just one more thing, when i import the mesh to Salome, it says there is intersecting mesh..I tried to use "merge by distance" already...